# How to install "stripe-php" library manually for stripe extension?

Tags: magento2, php, payment-methods

I would like to use the free stripe extension from Inchoo for my magento2 store in production.
I did not yet find out how to install the needed "stripe-php" library manually? I do not want to install that module with composer, but install everything manually.

This is the extension im talking about: https://github.com/Inchoo/magento2-Inchoo_Stripe

Where do i have to place the stripe-php folder library if I install manually?
  thanks alot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it manual, you need to add following in **lib/internal/Stripe** folder of Magento 2 root directory.

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/tree/master/lib

So all files and folders of above link will be under following folder.

```
<magento2-root-directory>/lib/internal/Stripe
```

Then those classes will be autoloaded. Then you can use that stripe classes as follows in your extension.

```
use Stripe\Account;
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to put the files in "/lib/internal/" or "/lib/internal/Stripe/"?  Do I need to change something in the extensions files from Inchoo for the payment module in "app/code/Inchoo/Stripe/"?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to install this extension via composer, you will be able to easy extension updates and so on, and no need to manage libraries yourself.

You can do following instructions:

```
composer config repositories.inchoostripe git https://github.com/Inchoo/magento2-Inchoo_Stripe.git
composer require inchoo/stripe:dev-master
```

https://github.com/Inchoo/magento2-Inchoo_Stripe#install